# Remove Duplicates from EventHub in Azure Stream Analytics

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-stream-analytics, stream-analytics

I have created an Azure stream Analytics Job which will get input data from EventHub and write to cosmosDB and Blob.

I could see sometimes the data from eventHub is duplicating and as a result duplicate data will be written to cosmosDB and Blob storage.

A sample input data into Stream Analytics from EventHub is shown below.

```
[
{
               "idnum":"00011XXX01",
               "basetime":0,
               "time":189834,
               "sig1":36.341587,
               "sig2":
               [
                              {
                                             "sig3":"04XXX",
                                             "id":1
                              },
                              {
                                             "sig3":"000000",
                                             "id":61
                              }
               ],
               "signals":
               [
                              {
                                             "timestamp":190915,
                                             "value":45,
                              },
                              {
                                             "timestamp":190915,
                                             "value":10.2,
                              },
                              {
                                             "timestamp":190915,
                              }
               ],
               "sig3TriggeredDateTime": {"dateTime":{"date":{"year":2019,"month":5,"day":16},"time":{"hour":4,"minute":56,"second":19,"nano":480389000}},"offset":{"totalSeconds":0}}
},
{
               "idnum":"00086XXX02",
               "basetime":0,
               "time":189834,
               "sig1":36.341587,
               "sig2":
               [
                              {
                                             "sig3":"03XXX",
                                             "id":1
                              },
                              {
                                             "sig3":"04XXX",
                                             "id":1
                              }
               ],
               "signals":
               [
                              {
                                             "timestamp":190915,
                                             "value":45,
                              },
                              {
                                             "timestamp":190915,
                                             "value":10.2,
                              },
                              {
                                             "timestamp":190915,
                              },
                              {
                                             "timestamp":190915,
                                             "value":0,
                              }
               ],
               "sig3TriggeredDateTime": {"dateTime":{"date":{"year":2019,"month":5,"day":16},"time":{"hour":4,"minute":56,"second":19,"nano":480389000}},"offset":{"totalSeconds":0}}
},
{
               "idnum":"00086XXX02",
               "basetime":0,
               "time":189834,
               "sig1":36.341587,
               "sig2":
               [
                              {
                                             "sig3":"03XXX",
                                             "id":1
                              },
                              {
                                             "sig3":"04XXX",
                                             "id":1
                              }
               ],
               "signals":
               [
                              {
                                             "timestamp":190915,
                                             "value":45,
                              },
                              {
                                             "timestamp":190915,
                                             "value":10.2,
                              },
                              {
                                             "timestamp":190915,
                              },
                              {
                                             "timestamp":190915,
                                             "value":0,
                              }
               ],
               "sig3TriggeredDateTime": {"dateTime":{"date":{"year":2019,"month":5,"day":16},"time":{"hour":4,"minute":56,"second":19,"nano":480389000}},"offset":{"totalSeconds":0}}
},{
               "idnum":"00086XXX02",
               "basetime":0,
               "time":189834,
               "sig1":36.341587,
               "sig2":
               [
                              {
                                             "sig3":"03XXX",
                                             "id":1
                              },
                              {
                                             "sig3":"04XXX",
                                             "id":1
                              }
               ],
               "signals":
               [
                              {
                                             "timestamp":190915,
                                             "value":45,
                              },
                              {
                                             "timestamp":190915,
                                             "value":10.2,
                              },
                              {
                                             "timestamp":190915,
                              },
                              {
                                             "timestamp":190915,
                                             "value":0,
                              }
               ],
               "sig3TriggeredDateTime": {"dateTime":{"date":{"year":2019,"month":5,"day":16},"time":{"hour":4,"minute":56,"second":19,"nano":480389000}},"offset":{"totalSeconds":0}}
},{
               "idnum":"00086XXX02",
               "basetime":0,
               "time":189834,
               "sig1":36.341587,
               "sig2":
               [
                              {
                                             "sig3":"03XXX",
                                             "id":1
                              },
                              {
                                             "sig3":"04XXX",
                                             "id":1
                              }
               ],
               "signals":
               [
                              {
                                             "timestamp":190915,
                                             "value":45,
                              },
                              {
                                             "timestamp":190915,
                                             "value":10.2,
                              },
                              {
                                             "timestamp":190915,
                              },
                              {
                                             "timestamp":190915,
                                             "value":0,
                              }
               ],
               "sig3TriggeredDateTime": {"dateTime":{"date":{"year":2019,"month":5,"day":16},"time":{"hour":4,"minute":56,"second":19,"nano":480389000}},"offset":{"totalSeconds":0}}
},
{
               "idnum":"00026XXX03",
               "basetime":0,
               "time":189834,
               "sig1":36.341587,
               "sig2":
               [
                              {
                                             "sig3":"03XXX",
                                             "id":1
                              },
                              {
                                             "sig3":"000000",
                                             "id":61
                              }
               ],
               "signals":
               [
                              {
                                             "timestamp":190915,
                                             "value":45,
                              },
                              {
                                             "timestamp":190915,
                                             "value":10.2,
                              }
               ],
               "sig3TriggeredDateTime": {"dateTime":{"date":{"year":2019,"month":5,"day":16},"time":{"hour":4,"minute":56,"second":19,"nano":480389000}},"offset":{"totalSeconds":0}}
}
]
```

In the above sample the event with **idnum: 00086XXX02** is duplicating 3 times.

I am doing the below analysis and obtaining the output with duplicates.

```
temp AS (
    SELECT
        input.idnum AS IDNUM,
        input.basetime AS BASETIME,
        input.time AS TIME,
        ROUND(input.sig1,5) AS SIG1,
        flatArrayElement as SIG2,
        udf.sgnlArrayMap(input.signals, input.basetime) AS SGNL //UDF to process the signals in input
    FROM [input01] as input
    CROSS APPLY GetArrayElements(input.sig2) AS flatArrayElement
    WHERE GetArrayLength(input.sig2) >=1
 ),
SIGNALS AS (
  SELECT * FROM temp T JOIN master M ON T.SIG2.ArrayValue.sig3 = M.sig3 
)

--Insert SIG2 to COSMOS Container
SELECT 
    t.IDNUM,
    t.BASETIME,
    t.TIME,
    t.SIG1,
    t.SIG2.ArrayValue.id AS ID,
    t.SIG2.ArrayValue.sig3 AS SIG3,
    t.SGNL
INTO [CosmosTbl]
FROM SIGNALS PARTITION BY PartitionId
```

The output will be as below where duplicate events are present for **"idnum":"00086XXX02"**

```
[
{
               "idnum":"00011XXX01",
               "basetime":0,
               "time":189834,
               "sig1":36.341587,
               "sig2":
               "sig3":"04XXX",
               "id":1
               "signals":
               [
                              {
                                             "timestamp":190915,
                                             "value":45,
                              },
                              {
                                             "timestamp":190915,
                                             "value":10.2,
                              },
                              {
                                             "timestamp":190915,
                              }
               ],
               "sig3TriggeredDateTime": {"dateTime":{"date":{"year":2019,"month":5,"day":16},"time":{"hour":4,"minute":56,"second":19,"nano":480389000}},"offset":{"totalSeconds":0}}
},
{
               "idnum":"00011XXX01",
               "basetime":0,
               "time":189834,
               "sig1":36.341587,
               "sig2":
               "sig3":"000000",
               "id":61
               "signals":
               [
                              {
                                             "timestamp":190915,
                                             "value":45,
                              },
                              {
                                             "timestamp":190915,
                                             "value":10.2,
                              },
                              {
                                             "timestamp":190915,
                              }
               ],
               "sig3TriggeredDateTime": {"dateTime":{"date":{"year":2019,"month":5,"day":16},"time":{"hour":4,"minute":56,"second":19,"nano":480389000}},"offset":{"totalSeconds":0}}
},                           
{
               "idnum":"00086XXX02",
               "basetime":0,
               "time":189834,
               "sig1":36.341587,
               "sig2":
               "sig3":"03XXX",
               "id":1
               "signals":
               [
                              {
                                             "timestamp":190915,
                                             "value":45,
                              },
                              {
                                             "timestamp":190915,
                                             "value":10.2,
                              },
                              {
                                             "timestamp":190915,
                              },
                              {
                                             "timestamp":190915,
                                             "value":0,
                              }
               ],
               "sig3TriggeredDateTime": {"dateTime":{"date":{"year":2019,"month":5,"day":16},"time":{"hour":4,"minute":56,"second":19,"nano":480389000}},"offset":{"totalSeconds":0}}
},
{
               "idnum":"00086XXX02",
               "basetime":0,
               "time":189834,
               "sig1":36.341587,
               "sig2":
               "sig3":"04XXX",
               "id":1
               "signals":
               [
                              {
                                             "timestamp":190915,
                                             "value":45,
                              },
                              {
                                             "timestamp":190915,
                                             "value":10.2,
                              },
                              {
                                             "timestamp":190915,
                              },
                              {
                                             "timestamp":190915,
                                             "value":0,
                              }
               ],
               "sig3TriggeredDateTime": {"dateTime":{"date":{"year":2019,"month":5,"day":16},"time":{"hour":4,"minute":56,"second":19,"nano":480389000}},"offset":{"totalSeconds":0}}
},
{
               "idnum":"00086XXX02",
               "basetime":0,
               "time":189834,
               "sig1":36.341587,
               "sig2":
               "sig3":"03XXX",
               "id":1
               "signals":
               [
                              {
                                             "timestamp":190915,
                                             "value":45,
                              },
                              {
                                             "timestamp":190915,
                                             "value":10.2,
                              },
                              {
                                             "timestamp":190915,
                              },
                              {
                                             "timestamp":190915,
                                             "value":0,
                              }
               ],
               "sig3TriggeredDateTime": {"dateTime":{"date":{"year":2019,"month":5,"day":16},"time":{"hour":4,"minute":56,"second":19,"nano":480389000}},"offset":{"totalSeconds":0}}
},
{
               "idnum":"00086XXX02",
               "basetime":0,
               "time":189834,
               "sig1":36.341587,
               "sig2":
               "sig3":"04XXX",
               "id":1
               "signals":
               [
                              {
                                             "timestamp":190915,
                                             "value":45,
                              },
                              {
                                             "timestamp":190915,
                                             "value":10.2,
                              },
                              {
                                             "timestamp":190915,
                              },
                              {
                                             "timestamp":190915,
                                             "value":0,
                              }
               ],
               "sig3TriggeredDateTime": {"dateTime":{"date":{"year":2019,"month":5,"day":16},"time":{"hour":4,"minute":56,"second":19,"nano":480389000}},"offset":{"totalSeconds":0}}
},
{
               "idnum":"00086XXX02",
               "basetime":0,
               "time":189834,
               "sig1":36.341587,
               "sig2":
               "sig3":"03XXX",
               "id":1
               "signals":
               [
                              {
                                             "timestamp":190915,
                                             "value":45,
                              },
                              {
                                             "timestamp":190915,
                                             "value":10.2,
                              },
                              {
                                             "timestamp":190915,
                              },
                              {
                                             "timestamp":190915,
                                             "value":0,
                              }
               ],
               "sig3TriggeredDateTime": {"dateTime":{"date":{"year":2019,"month":5,"day":16},"time":{"hour":4,"minute":56,"second":19,"nano":480389000}},"offset":{"totalSeconds":0}}
},
{
               "idnum":"00086XXX02",
               "basetime":0,
               "time":189834,
               "sig1":36.341587,
               "sig2":
               "sig3":"04XXX",
               "id":1
               "signals":
               [
                              {
                                             "timestamp":190915,
                                             "value":45,
                              },
                              {
                                             "timestamp":190915,
                                             "value":10.2,
                              },
                              {
                                             "timestamp":190915,
                              },
                              {
                                             "timestamp":190915,
                                             "value":0,
                              }
               ],
               "sig3TriggeredDateTime": {"dateTime":{"date":{"year":2019,"month":5,"day":16},"time":{"hour":4,"minute":56,"second":19,"nano":480389000}},"offset":{"totalSeconds":0}}
},
{
               "idnum":"00086XXX02",
               "basetime":0,
               "time":189834,
               "sig1":36.341587,
               "sig2":
               "sig3":"03XXX",
               "id":1
               "signals":
               [
                              {
                                             "timestamp":190915,
                                             "value":45,
                              },
                              {
                                             "timestamp":190915,
                                             "value":10.2,
                              },
                              {
                                             "timestamp":190915,
                              },
                              {
                                             "timestamp":190915,
                                             "value":0,
                              }
               ],
               "sig3TriggeredDateTime": {"dateTime":{"date":{"year":2019,"month":5,"day":16},"time":{"hour":4,"minute":56,"second":19,"nano":480389000}},"offset":{"totalSeconds":0}}
},
{
               "idnum":"00086XXX02",
               "basetime":0,
               "time":189834,
               "sig1":36.341587,
               "sig2":
               "sig3":"04XXX",
               "id":1
               "signals":
               [
                              {
                                             "timestamp":190915,
                                             "value":45,
                              },
                              {
                                             "timestamp":190915,
                                             "value":10.2,
                              },
                              {
                                             "timestamp":190915,
                              },
                              {
                                             "timestamp":190915,
                                             "value":0,
                              }
               ],
               "sig3TriggeredDateTime": {"dateTime":{"date":{"year":2019,"month":5,"day":16},"time":{"hour":4,"minute":56,"second":19,"nano":480389000}},"offset":{"totalSeconds":0}}
}
]
```

The Expected output will be events without duplicates (For the sample provided there shouldn't be duplicate events for "idnum":"00086XXX02")

Before writing the data into storage I want to remove the duplicate events. Is it possible to do from Stream Analytics?

Creating cosmos DB collection with Unique ID is a solution from Cosmos end, But here the table alreay exists and can we do anything from Stream Analytics end ?

Answer (score 0):

I simplify your test sql as below:

```
with t AS (
    SELECT
        flatArrayElement as SIG2
    FROM fromblob as input
    CROSS APPLY GetArrayElements(input.sig2) AS flatArrayElement
    WHERE GetArrayLength(input.sig2) >=1
 )
SELECT 
    t.SIG2.ArrayValue.id AS ID,
    t.SIG2.ArrayValue.sig3 AS SIG3
FROM t PARTITION BY PartitionId
```

And it produces duplicate data because of `GetArrayElements()` method which is normal i think.The array is split, the result should be duplicated definitely.

Based on my experience and my [findings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/stream-analytics-query/query-language-elements-azure-stream-analytics)(plus this [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270577-stream-analytics/suggestions/37437577-duplicate-outputs)),there is no distinct method in ASA. The reason i think is that ASA processes real-time stream data,not static data something like SQL table.It can't judge whether the data is duplicate during per time unit.

Combined with the last cosmos db case([How to find Duplicate documents in Cosmos DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59213815/how-to-find-duplicate-documents-in-cosmos-db)), i think the key point of solution is getting the root cause : why the event hub processes duplicate source data. Surely,you could set a cosmos db trigger to prevent the duplicate data from streaming into db.But i think it's not an effective way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Distinct to remove duplicate events.  There is online documentation available:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-stream-analytics-query-patterns#remove-duplicate-events-in-a-window

Example:

```
With Temp AS ( 
SELECT      
  COUNT(DISTINCT Time) AS CountTime,    
  Value,    
  DeviceId  
FROM   Input TIMESTAMP BY Time  
GROUP BY   Value,  DeviceId,   SYSTEM.TIMESTAMP() 
)  
SELECT  
  AVG(Value) AS AverageValue,  
  DeviceId  
INTO Output  
FROM Temp  
GROUP BY DeviceId,TumblingWindow(minute, 5)
```